# Get value from input

Tags: jquery

I'm very new to jQuery so this might be a stupid question. I'm using a jQuery datepicker and I'm trying to fetch the date from an input to a simple `<div>`.

The page works like this:

1. You select a date with jQuery datepicker.
2. You select a time with jQuery timepicker.
3. You select a place with a normal select box.
4. A text will come up and you have to verify the date,time and place.

I'm having a problem getting the values from the inputs.

When I use this script nothing happens:

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#datum").text(value);
}).keyup();
```

I have a `div` with `id="datum"` where I want to display the results.

My datepicker code looks like this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker( {
    onSelect: function(date) {
        $("#pick_time").show(); // Go to step 2
    },
    showWeek: true,
    firstDay: 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the keyup function for `$('input')`.  Use `.blur()` instead.

```
$("input").blur(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#datnum").text(value);
});
```