# Type into a field, and use jQuery/JS to display this value lower on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple task which I'm failing at.

I want to take this field:

```
<input id="amount" name="amount" value="{$formRefill.amount}" class="textInput auto required validateNumber" type="text">
```

And once the user has typed a value in there (i.e. `950.50`), and they click outside of text field (focus somewhere else), jQuery takes this field and displays it somewhere else on the page.

I was trying to do this inside of a DIV lower down the page.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get value from input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640375/get-value-from-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) or the [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event. Use change if you want the value to copy only when it has been changed, or blur if you want it to copy regardless.

```
$('#myText').blur(function () {
   $('#myDiv').text($(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AAyyq/

Comment: Ok, and what if I wanted to add a dollar sign on this output...? Sorry, still learning JS/Query

Comment: this will work only when the focus will be taken out of the input.

Comment: @Shackrock just add a $ to the text value you are assigning- http://jsfiddle.net/AAyyq/2/

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event of the input field:

```
$('#amount').change(function() {
    $('#mydivid').text($(this).val());
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/yg9gF/2/

Comment: Ok, and what if I wanted to add a dollar sign on this output...?  Sorry, still learning JS/Query

Comment: this will work only when the focus will be taken out of the input.

Answer (score 4):

you should use `keyup` which will update the div on every `char` entered.

```
$('#amount').on('keyup',function() {
    $('#mydiv').text($(this).val());
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yg9gF/11/

Comment: This answer should be the best answer here